# Is there an effective way to use System.Threading.Tasks with WCF service proxies?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, task-parallel-library

After reading a [recent MSDN Magazine article about the Task scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff959203.aspx) I was hoping (and actually quite excited) that using it would benefit my use of WCF generated proxies.

I was hoping to get some of the following benefits :

- **1) Ability to abort a running WCF operation** (I'm not expecting this to stop the operation on the server - I'd just like to be able to signal that 'I don't want the result for this task'. This is especially common in UI where someone repeatedly selects items from a grid that trigger service calls.)
- **2) Ability to start a task at some point other than when it was created** - I'm not sure I really *need* this, I just thought it might be nice to generate a task and not immediately run it. After all I thought that was the whole point of tasks.
- **3) Bindable properties** - so I can bind my WCF UI to `IsCompleted` and let the Task class abstract away the operation's internals from my UI.
- **4) Ability to abstract away the running of the operation** - mocking, blah blah blah, future refactoring etc.

However - I don't seem to get ANY of these benefits.

- 1) There is no abort functionality in Task - which strikes me as really odd.
- 2) The only overload that I could get working with `Task.Factory.FromAsync<>` is the one shown below. This immediately begins execution of the webservice operation (as seen in Fiddler) and doesn't let me start the call later.
- 3) Task doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so i can't bind it to the UI.
- 4) This one is kind of dead in the water given the other 3 benefits aren't happening :-(

Sooo.... Am i just wasting my time trying to get WCF generated proxies working with Tasks -- or am I missing something.

```
// WCF client
var client = new ShoppingCartClient();

// create task
var t = Task.Factory.FromAsync<GetOrderDetailsMsgOut>(
              client.BeginGetOrderDetails(new GetOrderDetailsMsgIn()
              {
                  OrderId = 12345
              },  null, null),    
              client.EndGetOrderDetails);

t.ContinueWith(x =>
{
    var order = x.Result.Order;
    // do something with order
});
```

Comment: What do you see as the difference between the Abort functionality you're looking for, and the Cancel functionality present in Task?

Comment: @john - exactly the same - but there is no Cancel() method either. there IS an IsCancelled method, but no Cancel(). although  I see now that i can cancel using a cancellation token http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx

Comment: CancellationToken is the way to do a cancel.

Comment: @john - but when doing FromAsync i can't specify one. unless I create the task as an action, but then there's the threadpool concerns to worry about

Answer (score 1):

As a part of the new Async capabilities Microsoft are planning for the next version of C#, they have released a CTP [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=4738205d-5682-47bf-b62e-641f6441735b&displaylang=en), it is compatible with VS 2010 SP1.

A while back ago, I wrote a small blog post about one of the samples that is bundled with the CTP, about the [TaskWsdlImportExtension](http://www.larswilhelmsen.com/2010/11/05/taskwsdlimportextensiona-hidden-gem-in-the-c-vnext-async-ctp-samples/).